# Windows web service error - Error string with resource id '0x88' is not found for the language id '0x809'

Tags: web-services, visual-c++

I am developing an application using Windows Web Service API in VC++. For error handling I am using the APIs `WsGetErrorProperty()` and `WsGetErrorString()`. When I call the latter API, `WsGetErrorString()`, I get the following error:
[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPyYV.png)

> Error string with resource id '0x88' is not found for the language id
>   '0x809'

The problem happens on Windows 10 Enterprise 64bit. I tried changing the system locale to US, still the problem persists.
On all other Windows platforms (Windows 10 Enterprise 32bit, Windows 10 Pro 32/64bit, Windows 7 32/64 bit etc) it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Does United Kingdom (GB) work? See [Language Identifier Constants and Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318693(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: I have already tried setting up the lang id to US/UK, unfortunately this did not work.

Answer (score 0):

When making the WWSAPI call on the server side, make sure that the WS_ERROR that's passed in is created with the property:

WS_ERROR_PROPERTY_LANGID set to 1033 (US-English).

In other words:

```
WS_ERROR *CreateWSError()
{
   WS_ERROR *ws_error;
   LANGID lang = MAKELANGID(1033, SUBLANG_NEUTRAL);
   WS_ERROR_PROPERTY prop = {WS_ERROR_PROPERTY_LANGID, &lang, sizeof(lang)};
   WsCreateError(&prop, 1, &ws_error);
   return ws_error;
}
```

and pass the returned pointer to subsequent calls.

On the client side:

WS_PROXY_PROPERTY prop = { WS_PROXY_FAULT_LANG_ID, &lang, sizeof(lang)};

XXXX_CreateServiceProxy(0, // template value
&prop, // properties
1, // property count
&serviceProxy,
error)))